# Predicate logic question

Tags: logic

Let $P$ be a $2$-ary predicate.   Is it true that

$$\forall x, y P(x, y)$$

is equivalent to

$$\forall x, y P(x, y) \wedge P(y, x)$$

This seems obviously true, but how do you formally prove it?

Comment: I believe you would have to demonstrate that $P(x,y)\leftrightarrow{P(y,x)}$. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @ZettaSuro What you are saying (i.e. $P$ is symmetric) would be necessary if we wanted to show, for any $a,b$ that $P(a,b)$ is equivalent to $P(a,b)\wedge P(b,a)$.  But the quantifiers allow the argument to through.  This got me too for a second: if P(x,y) is "$x<y$, then we can't say for any $a,b$ that $a<b$ is equivalent to $a<b\wedge b<a$.  But with the quantifiers, the two sentences are false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Suppose it is true that:

> $$
> \forall x,y,~~P(x,y) \iff \boxed{\forall a,b,~~P(a,b)}
> $$

Then by letting $a:=x$ and $b:=y$, we know that:
$$
\boxed{\forall x,y,~~P(x,y)}
$$
Likewise, by letting $a:=y$ and $b:=x$, we know that:
$$
\forall y,x,~~P(y,x) \iff \boxed{\forall x,y,~~P(y,x)}
$$
Hence, it follows that:

> $$
> \forall x,y,~~[P(x,y) \land P(y,x)]
> $$

Comment: This only seems to take the argument one way ...

Comment: @MarkBennet Conversely, suppose that $\forall x,y,~~[P(x,y) \land P(y,x)]$. Then by conjunction elimination, we have $∀x,y,~~P(x,y)$, as desired. This was only a hint, so I figured it would be okay to omit this part.

Answer (score 0):

From
$$\tag0\forall x\forall y P(x,y)$$
by specialization (with $u$ being a "new/unused" variable)
$$\forall y P(u,y)$$
and by specialization again
$$P(u,x)$$
hence by generalization 
$$\forall u P(u,x)$$
and by another specialization
$$\tag1P(y,x).$$
Also, by specialization from $(0)$
$$\forall yP(x,y)$$
and by another specialization 
$$\tag2 P(x,y).$$
Now from $(1)$ and $(2)$ by conjunction
$$P(x,y)\land P(y,x)$$
and by generalization
$$\forall y (P(x,y)\land P(y,x))$$
and finally
$$\forall x\forall y( P(x,y)\land P(y,x)).$$
So far we have
$$\forall x\forall y P(x,y)\vdash \forall x\forall y (P(x,y)\land P(y,x))$$
hence by the deduction theorem
$$(3)\forall x\forall y P(x,y)\rightarrow \forall x\forall y (P(x,y)\land P(y,x)).$$

---

For the other direction, from
$$\forall x\forall y( P(x,y)\land P(y,x))$$
by specialization
$$\forall y( P(x,y)\land P(y,x))$$
and then 
$$ P(x,y)\land P(y,x)$$
and by conjunction elimination
$$ P(x,y)$$
and by generalization again
$$\forall y P(x,y)$$
and finally
$$\forall x\forall y P(x,y).$$
Thus
$$ \forall x\forall y (P(x,y)\land P(y,x))\vdash \forall x\forall y P(x,y)$$
and by the deduction theorem
$$\tag4 \forall x\forall y (P(x,y)\land P(y,x))\rightarrow \forall x\forall y P(x,y).$$

From $(3)$ and $(4)$ we have by biconditional introduction
$$ \forall x\forall y P(x,y)\leftrightarrow \forall x\forall y (P(x,y)\land P(y,x))$$
as desired.

Comment: This only seems to take the argument one way ... the other way is obvious, but needs to be stated, I think?

Comment: @MarkBennet Good point. Nothing is really obvious and th eOP specifically asked for a formal proof of the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** I always like to explicitly specify a domain of quantification. IMHO, this makes for a more intuitive and "math-like" proof. So, with $U$ as the domain of quantification, the problem becomes to prove:

$\forall x,y (x,y\in U \to P(x,y))\leftrightarrow \forall x,y (x,y\in U \to P(x,y)\wedge P(y,x))$

(Some philosophy instructors may take exception to introducing set theoretic notation like this. Too "math-like".)

For '$\to$':

Assume $\forall x,y (x,y\in U \to P(x,y))$. Assume $a,b\in U$. Then obtain both $P(a,b)$ and $P(b,a)$, and generalize as required.

For '$\leftarrow$':

Assume $\forall x,y (x,y\in U \to P(x,y)\wedge P(y,x))$.  Assume $a,b\in U$. Then obtain $P(a,b)$, and generalize as required.